# Perl regex to unserialize data?

Tags: php, regex, perl, serialization

I am facing issue related to serialized data. I have serialized data like below:

```
a:1:{i:1;a:3:{s:8:\"question\";s:18:\"What do you think?\";s:6:\"choice\";a:2:{i:1;s:3:\"Yes\";i:2;s:2:\"No\";}s:5:\"votes\";a:2:{i:1;i:1;i:2;i:0;}}}
```

Now I want to unserialize this data using perl regex to an array like below:

```
Array ( [question] => Who is going to be the Wild Cards in the AFC? [multi] => 1 [choice] => Array ( [1] => Cincinnati [2] => Jacksonville [3] => New York Jets [4] => Kansas City [5] => Denver [6] => Other ) [votes] => Array ( [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 1 [4] => 1 [5] => 0 [6] => 0 ) )
```

Comment: How is your data serialised initially? It looks like it's trying to be something like JSON, but it isn't quite?

Comment: If you have any influence over how the data is serialized, make sure it's a known format with a Perl library to deserialize it, such as JSON. Regexes aren't a good fit her because of the recursion (the arbitrarily nestable brackets); Perl regexes can deal with that in principle but I don't find them easy enough to understand.

Comment: That doesn't look like valid JSON.

Comment: Can you please provide the serialization corresponding to the input? You just showed two independent strings in different formats.

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/~bobtfish/PHP-Serialization-0.34/lib/PHP/Serialization.pm

Comment: PHP::Serialization's `unserialize` doesn't work. It croaks on the line feeds and the backslashes.

Comment: @ikegami so does php https://eval.in/303419

Comment: Thanks for ans. I have get it work by using PHP::Serialization' module.

Answer (score 2):

If this was the output of PHP's `serialize`, you could use the following to get a data structure:

```
use PHP::Serialization qw( unserialize );
my $data = unserialize($serialized);
```

However, the seralized string was mangled by the addition of line feeds, spaces and backslashes. As such, you will need to write a custom parser for this unique format.

Comment: I have loaded this module and get it serialized as per requirement. Thanks!